# How do I access an attribute from a Flask-SQLAlchemy Query object in a Jinja2 template document?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Upon a successful login, I save the *user* object (from query) to the *session* dictionary.

When I try to access an attribute of the object in my Jinja template, I get an error.

Below are the codes for the affected parts:

**Python "views.py" file:**

```
session['in_session'] = True
session['active_user'] = user
```

**Jinja2 "base.html" file:**

```
{% if session.in_session %}
    <li><a href="">Signed in as {{session.active_user.username|safe|title}}!</a></li>
{%endif%}
```

---

---

**EDIT-1:**
Here's the error *traceback*:

```
TypeError
```

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app

response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1479, in full_dispatch_request

response = self.process_response(response)

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1693, in process_response

self.save_session(ctx.session, response)

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 837, in save_session

return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 326, in save_session

val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 537, in dumps

payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 809, in dump_payload

json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 522, in dump_payload

return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 85, in dumps

return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 126, in dumps

rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps

sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 209, in encode

chunks = list(chunks)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode

for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict

for chunk in chunks:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode

o = _default(o)

File "/home/acetakwas/web_dev/flask/flask_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 83, in default

return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default

raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

TypeError: <User 2: u'tak'; u'ace@tak.was'> is not JSON serializable
```

---

---

**EDIT-2:**
I've just figured that the issue is with storing the *user* object returned from my query as a dictionary value. So assuming I have a **User** class which extends **Model** (from the *SQLAlchemy* library), doing something like this will fail:

```
session['active_user'] = User.query.filter_by(username='my_user_name').first()
```

**Why is that?**

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to post errors you are encountering. But if I had to guess, you stated session is a dict. In your code you are accessing session like an object. You should be able to simply do:

```
{{session['active_user'].username|safe|title}}
```

Comment: `session['active_user']` and `session.active_user` are the same thing in Jinja2.

Comment: I didn't know that. Still, can you post your error?

Comment: @Spencer Yes, you're right; I should have posted the error. I'll try to update my question. However, as I am not with my computer at the moment, I can give an idea: "Query object is not JSON serializable". The error is something like that.

Comment: Ah. You probably aren't executing the query before you send it to the view. I will update answer.